# An action to export a Photoshop document with file name intact

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, actions

Is there a way to export a document in Photoshop using an action that would preserve the file name? Example: I have a document called `Home.psd`. I'd like to run an action, and it would create a `Home.png` in some specified location, like the Desktop. I can do all of this pretty easily by recording the action, except to set the save destination and file type, I must enter a name.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this ( newest foles can be found in github ): http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/file-backups-for-photoshop/16968#16968 The only big difference is that it saves .psd. it wouldn't be difficult to change it to save a png instead... or additionally

Comment: ...and I love you too, man.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up editing his script to make my own:
https://github.com/edwardloveall/Photoshop-Export-PSD-script

What's proper etiquette for posting it somewhere? Should I comment on plainclothes' answer to link to this or make my own answer?

Comment: Since it is what you were looking for, posting it as an answer would be a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up making my own script based on advice from [plainclothes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/17433/9906) and a link from [Joonas](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/an-action-to-export-a-photoshop-document-with-file-name-intact?noredirect=1#comment23563_17432)

You can find the script here: https://github.com/edwardloveall/Photoshop-Export-PSD-script

By default, it saves to the Desktop, but just edit the line

```
var desktop               = '~/Desktop';
```

to change the destination.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be completely hands-off I believe **you need a script**.

If you had a lot of files to process, **you could batch the action** and automate the name and destination there. But that still requires your intervention at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can [create an action](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29927/creating-action-using-photoshop) to save the images as you want and then simply use this action in the "batch" command found in the menu "file" then "automate"

There you can choose what folder to use for the images you want to process, and also WHERE you want them to be saved.

You can also simply select the "extension" as shown in the screenshot below; it will save your image with the same name, but will add the right extension.

[image: Automate Batch]