# How can I create an action in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

How can I create my own Action using Photoshop? Can anyone guide me with a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open action panel: `Window` - `Actions`

Click the little arrow in the corner of the panel, and choose `new action`

[image]

Give your action a name, click `record`

Proceed to do the actions you want to record. When done, click stop (little square in the player)

[image]

Now you have recorded an action, and you can apply this to any image by opening the Action panel, choosing the action you created, and press play.

Answer (score 1):

Here is steps to do it.

You can refer below video guide.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQE2HQ8P-LI

1. Go to Menu > Window > Action
2. You can see we have all images of 500x500. "Converd" wil be destination folder where we will save images.
3. Create new set by click on folder icon in action widget. Give any name.
   4.Create new action. You can see set name, we just created in last step. Give a name to action here.Click on "Record" button.
4. You can see red circle, that means recording has been started. Now whatever you will do, will get recorded as action.
5. Menu > File > Open > choose file
6. Menu > Image > Image resize
7. Give a width. In this example it is 300px.
8. You can see, commands ( Open, Image size ), under choose action.
9. Now save the image for web device in jpeg format. Choose a destinatin folder.
10. Now close the file. You can see commands recorded.
11. Click on stop button, to stop action recording.
12. Now its time to repeat action, before that I removed file from destination folder.
13. Menu > File > Automate > Batch
14. Select the name of set and action, you created in last steps. Choose source files folder (files to be resized) and destination files folder (where resized files will be saved). Check all options according to you. And you are done. It will start resizing images and save in destinatoin foler automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Establish your own Photoshop activities in 5 easy steps

1. Open the Actions panel. When you open the Actions panel in Photoshop CC this is what you see
2. Tape-record your task. Recording activity is easy
3. Play the activity. When playing activities, you have a couple of choices
4. Handling as well as editing and enhancing activities. You can make use of an action to various other photos after it has actually been videotaped
5. For excellent results

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! Please don't forget to check the date of the post before answering: author probably already made his action 5 years ago.