# Easily save .png from Photoshop without any dialog?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, png, save

I'm currently working on a graphic, where as soon as I update the image (save the file), the window updates itself. However, every time I want to save, I have to switch the file from a PSD to a PNG, set the compression, etc. I'm hoping there's an option to just Ctrl + S, and have the .png's file update automatically.

I have tried "Quick Export as PNG" but that doesn't actually save a file anywhere. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Create an action for this

Comment: It's 2019, Photoshop 2020 and Adobe still didn't give us the `[X] Do not ask again` checkbox on the PNG format options popup

Answer (score 9):

Well, the best, easiest, coolest, fastest way I could ever find of saving as a PNG without confirmation or any other kind of dialog is:

1. Open your document
2. Open the **Actions** tab and **Create a new action** named **PNG FastSave**
3. Go to **File** -> **Save for web&devices**
4. In the upper right corner select **PNG** instead of **GIF** and hit **Save** and *choose where to save it*.
5. Go back to **Actions** tab and **Stop Recording**

...now, whatever changes you make to your document, when Playing that action it will automatically save it as a PNG over the file that you saved at step 4. To make things even faster you can :

6. Go to **Edit** -> **Keyboard Shortcurs**
7. Choose **Panel Menus** from the "*Shortcuts For:*" dropdown
8. Click on **Actions** -> **Play** from the **Panel Menu Command** then enter a key-combo for a shortcut (say **Shift+Ctrl+/** PS: you actually have to press the combo for it to show) and click **OK**

### Now, whenever you hit that combo (Shift+Ctrl+/) it will automatically save your PNG without any notifications, alerts or whatever.

Clean and fast (tested).

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to save automatically upon each change/action I make, without even hitting the hotkey?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to create and save an action, tie it to a combination of keys and press them anytime you need to export.

---

I don't have PhotoShop on this computer and when I have it I can't access StackExchange, so I hope someone can chime in and detail the limitations and procedure of this method.

Meanwhile, you can read https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29928/15541 and hope it's still valid for your PhotoShop version.

Not everything can be recorded on actions, but once created, an action can be edited from the actions menu by adding specific menu commands like "save as" or "export".

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a droplet.

Droplets are drag-and-drop mini-applications — essentially applets — in macro form that can exist outside Photoshop on your desktop, on your taskbar, or within a folder. They’re always available, so you can apply them to any image files you want. Think of them as batches waiting to happen.

You just need to drag the file or files that you want to process onto the droplet. Photoshop doesn’t even have to be open at the time. When you drop the file or files, the droplet opens Photoshop and carries out the steps in the action embedded in the droplet’s instructions. **You must use an existing action as the core of the droplet.**

To create a droplet, follow these steps:

Choose File→Automate→Create Droplet.

The Create Droplet dialog box opens.
[image]

In the Save Droplet In area, click the Choose button and enter a name and location on your hard drive for the droplet application. (Don't worry, you will be able to select where will your processed images will save at in a further step)

The location isn’t of overriding importance because after you create the droplet, you can drag it to your desktop, a toolbar, or wherever you like.

The rest of the Create Droplet dialog box is the same as the Batch dialog box, except that you don’t have to specify a source. **Droplets use the files dropped on them as their source files.**

In the Play area, select the actions set, action, and options. (this is the only confusing bit if you are not used to actions, but in few words you gotta have an action previously recorded with all the steps you want your images to go through every time you drop a file on the droplet)

Select a destination from the Destination pop-up menu.

Specify any file-naming options you want.

Specify how Photoshop should process errors.

When you finish, click OK to create the droplet.

To use the droplet, just select the file, files, or folders that you want to process and drag them to the droplet applet.

[Original article.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-droplets-in-photoshop-cs6.html)

Comment: The whole point of the question is that going through the Save dialog isn't quick enough so I would say leaving Photoshop and finding the file to drag on to a droplet is probably no better.

Comment: Droplets are a great solution in general though, I just don't think they fix the problem here :)

Comment: Well, it is indeed the Save dialog's steps and config what makes it tedious. Adding all the facts he's asking for (avoiding file type selection, compression and extra configuration, saving path, etc...) I find lots better to have a droplet on my desktop or folder.

Comment: Sorry, got posted before finishing! Leaving Photoshop shouldn't be a pain, Cmd+Tab (or Alt+Tab) and you could be right on your desktop or folder :)  .

Comment: Like I said, I think it's a great solution in general but not to the normal mid workflow cmd+s save. I save with cmd+s probably hundreds of times a day, if I had to leave the program and find the file to save it wouldn't be worth it and I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

You can just <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> a PNG. A few points things you need to do first:

- First make sure the file *already is* a PNG. So either open a PNG or Save As a PNG first
- Make sure there are no layers. As soon as your file has layers it will try and Save As a PSD, unless it already is a format that supports layers (PNG doesn't). So `Layer -> Flatten Image`if you have any layers.

So all you need to do is make sure the file already is a PNG then every time you want to save, quickly flatten the image, Save then Undo the flattening.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this answer makes complete sense and it's the simplest.

Comment: Thanks! Guess its not *clever* enough :) ..I get It's not perfect but if your editing a PNG and need to do quick saves without messing around setting up actions this is the by far the easiest way

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but this doesnt work for me. Even if I open a PNG and press Ctrl+S, PS wants to saved as a PSD.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Photoshop CC you could group all your layers and name the group the name of your file with a `.png` at the end. For example `image.png`. The go to `File > Generate > Image Assets` now it'll save your PNG every time you make changes to any of the layers in the group.

[More information on image assets](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html)