# Same procedure for each image in Photoshop: how to speed up the production?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, photoshop-scripting

Id' like to know if exists a way to speed up the production in Photoshop in the following case:
I have several images and I have to apply for each one of them the same adjustment. Doing it manually is very time consuming.
So, is there a way to automatize this process?

Comment: yes . use actions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvdtFoetEmc ! or batch processing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcXwhrvHu3w !

Comment: @DesignPhoenix that's an answer, why is it in the comments?

Comment: actually there is many asnwers to similar questions! seems i'll just post those links then

Comment: This is quite a broad question (check [ask]) and it has already been asked  (e.g. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29927/creating-action-using-photoshop) please use the search function in the website and [edit] your question if you need some more specific help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few posts from GDSE for making [**an action**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29927/creating-action-using-photoshop) and batching [**images by action**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66292/how-can-i-use-automate-batch-action-of-adobe-photoshop-to-cut-5px-for-every-imag).
And here are YouTube resources for making [**an action**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvdtFoetEmc) and batching [**images**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcXwhrvHu3w).

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive reply. Does this technique works even if I have to work with multiple images, and not only with filter and adjustments? For example, I have 3 RGB images and I want to copy the G channel of the second image into the first one, and the B channel of the third one into the first one.

Comment: Nevermid, I did it and it was extremely simple! Thanks!

Comment: yes you can practically record everything but actions have limitations like they don't understand layer order. if you click on second layer then it'll recorded with name instead of layer order . it'll all be cleared once you get habitated of actions :D