# Git-style Managing for Graphics/Programming Assets on Filesystem level?

Tags: resource-recommendations, osx, asset-management

*This [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5003/digital-asset-management-software-recommendations) addresses my problem about handling derivative works but I am trying to find some Git compatible solution. Extensis Portfolio may be a good candidate but for me it is essential that I am able to work smoothly between graphics assets repo and programming repo. SourceTree/Git combo works to with programming projects but graphics easily ruins things because the graphics repo can expand extremely fast.*

Suppose a screenshot/work/etc with specific time-stamp/index/description, I don't want to lose this origin but I still need to use this work for things such as sprite-generation so I have change its description and location. In Git, I would use `git mv` to maintain the history -- now I want that the GUI will automatically handle this without me typing this command. Another scenario: I need to create many different versions of the same image so I clone many of them and change the name, I want the GUI to handle this in a way that I can later come back and see graphically how different art assets evolved. Extensis Portfolio apparently requires you to set up some groups but I would like the GUI to handle the group creation the time I create a new folder -- in a way I am trying to find a solution that is closely tied to the file system and Git: the software cannot add everyhing to Git unless the exponential size increasing easily.

**Does there exist any software to manage the evolution graphics assets on file-system level?**

> The file-system level means that I could just create folder/file and then it tracked the evolution of files automatically like each file is an object where a field stores its historical paths.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is too late, but the best thing I've come across thus far for this is: https://layervault.com/

Simple, user friendly version control AND you can try it out 30 days FOR FREE.

Comment: ...makes sanse +1, never too late to improve! *"We can do better. We have to do better."* Integration to Github, Dropbox, etc, fascinating service, thank you. How do you design your repository if you integrate it with your other developer repos? Do you use git-submodule for graphics assets that other devs can clone? Or public branch and stable branch separate where programmers have only access to the public branch while designers have access to both stable and public branches?

Answer (score 1):

**Just stick with SourceTree.** I handle all my webs comps, production art, and even branding and print projects in Git. Works flawlessly.

**Moving to a true VCS has made a vast reduction in my disk space consumption.** An important thing to remember about Git and SVN: They both maintain an *incremental* history of your files, even binary files. So your long trail of versions (or branches and tags) are only as big as the changes you made.

**Another thing I like about this workflow is tagging (archives) and branching (experiments).** We use tags to archive the state of a project when a big update is released. Branches can't be integrated like code projects, but I've started using them to explore speculative reworks. We just overwrite the trunk when it becomes an official project.

I wouldn't bother introducing something new into your workflow. You have the right tools in place already.

Comment: I have read that SVN and Git sometimes have problems with large binary files because of {magic}. The worst case being small-byte-count changes being seen as MB scale changes. Do you see this? Also, do you just "commit" at the end of the day, every 5 mins, automagically [...]?

Comment: I've never personally had trouble using SourceTree (Git) or Cornerstone (SVN). That includes files crossing the hundred mb mark. With users who take their files in and out of the local VC directory repeatedly (not sure why) I have had a few corruptions in Cornerstone. But never with SourceTree or using SVN through the Terminal or Eclipse. We try to commit no less than once a day when working on a project. I don't bother updating too often for small things I don't mind recreating ;)

Comment: I used SVN for a short time for code only, but it is mostly overkill for me as the only "developer" (to use the term loosely). Presumably Git works like SVN, where you "pull" to a local folder, make new files locally and "add" them to tracking, then "push" the changed files by pushing the folder or the individual files? Basically you use the OS file browser with hooks to GIT functionality?