# Where can I get regular webdesign exercise tasks?

Tags: website-design, logo, html, inspiration

Over the past year, my portfolio has become pretty leaned towards photography. I'm fresh out of university, so I don't have much client work to show. The thing is, while I can always find subjects to photograph or think of some interesting photography project, I have a hard time coming up with design/web design projects 'just for the sake of it'. However, I really need some exercise in that area as well as some finished projects to show in my portfolio. So I'm looking for some kind of community, blog or whatever where I can find regular design/web design tasks. Ideally something where I get to work with InDesign, Illustrator, Photoshop, HTML/CSS et c. alternately and/or in conjuntion. Something where I get to train my intuition and skills for design as a whole.

For example, for programmers there's the [dailyprogrammer subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/). I'm looking for something like that, but with a focus on screen/web design projects. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you really can't find clients (going to local businesses and seeing if there's anything you can do might be a start),  you can consider helping out open source projects. See [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/46428/23061) to see how

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to have current web design skills, you could complete courses online and be able to list those on your existing website. There are many places with online courses. Example: MIT offers free courses: https://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm and TutsPlus is used by many companies and the name is fairly respected. https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/

You could always volunteer your web design skills for non-profit organizations in your community or nationally and be able to feature the projects you have worked on. For example your local humane society, women's shelters, homeless shelters, children's services, churches, volunteer groups, etc.

All while continuing what it appears you enjoy more, photography.

Comment: That wasn't quite what I'm looking for, but it's still a good idea! I will try some of the tutsplus tutorials for a start. Thanks!