# Ways to practice design as a student without a subject or project

Tags: interface-design, games, inspiration

I am studying design in school but I want to make things outside of class. Only problem is that I cannot think of anything to design. I want to practice designing UI for games but how do I design a UI for something that doesn't exist?

I really just want to put a lot of hours into practicing but I almost find that impossible without a client and a problem to solve. I just can't come up with a game and design a UI for it when it's not a real thing. Any advise would help a lot!

Comment: [This post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/46428/23061) might help you

Answer (score 1):

> I want to practice designing UI for games but how do I design a UI for
>   something that doesn't exist?

How about a UI for something that **does** exist?

There are several games in early access that are still working on their interfaces, as well as open source games that could definitely use some help. Redesigns are a good way to practise, and if you do decide to collaborate with an existing game you can use Github (for example) to then propose your changes and perhaps get them implemented.

- Early access games on Steam: http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Early%20Access/
- Open source games on GitHub: https://github.com/leereilly/games

Comment: I am definitely going to look into this more thanks!